# rxjs , switchMap ,interval, provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

trying to get data from a server, interval to a service every 10 sec.
and if the price is returned, then stop the interval. code below:

but im getting error:

> ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was
>   expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

code:

```
public Respond() {

this.dataService.WaitingForServiceRespond()
  .pipe((
    debounceTime(2000),
    switchMap((r: any) => {
      if (!r.price) {
        setInterval(() => {
          return this.Respond();
        }, 10000)
      } else {

        this.dataService.user.payment = r;
        console.log('price returned', r);
        return ''
      }
    })
  ))
  .subscribe(e => {
    console.log(e)
  })
```

}

Comment: Can you please share the response?

Comment: The function passed to switchMap is supposed to return an Observable (or a type as described in the error message). But if r.price is falsy, it doesn't return anything. And if it's truthy, it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your `switchMap`. It expects to return a stream. You return nothing as you use `setInterval`. You can return an `Observable` by returning `interval()` of `rxjs` instead of calling `setInterval()`.

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
...

public Respond() {

this.dataService.WaitingForServiceRespond()
  .pipe((
    debounceTime(2000),
    switchMap((r: any) => {
      if (!r.price) {

        return interval(10000).pipe(tap(() => this.Respond()))

      } else {

        this.dataService.user.payment = r;
        console.log('price returned', r);
        return of('')
      }
    })
  ))
  .subscribe(e => {
    console.log(e)
  })
}
```

Comment: And this still return an empty string if r.price is truthy.

Comment: You still dont return anything too in the if condition.

Comment: @HarunYılmaz  still getting You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: Ah sorry. I forgot to write `return` before `interval`. Edited the answer

Comment: @HarunYılmaz Argument of type '(r: any) => Observable<number> | Observable<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<number>'.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't help you further without knowing the content of `this.dataService.WaitingForServiceRespond()` and `this.Respond()`.

Comment: @HarunYılmaz adding to the return value string  fix the problem:   return (interval(10000).pipe(tap(() => this.Respond())), '1');